# how to map a json store or xml store to pie chart in sencha architect

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect, sencha-charts

Am new to sencha and all its products.  I started working with sencha architect.  In that when i design some project and when i try to run its asking for url and i uploaded it on a free web hosting site. [MY test app](http://praveen.comyr.com/sencha/test1/app.html). When i preview it its showing an empty page. I thinks that its may be because of not providing any data for piechart. can anybody guide me how to add store in jsonstore or xmlstore and map it to a pie chart. videos highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you right click on desktop safari/chrome and choose inspect element when running your app, then look in your console, what error do you see?

Comment: Thanks. Its not the error in the code. The problem is in the structure of my json. Now i solved it